# Unit test for POJO using Mockito

Tags: java, list, junit, mockito, pojo

I have a POJO class with another POJO variable

```java
class Rows 
{
    private List<RowName> rowName; //RowName is another POJO with String variables
    //getter & setter
}
```

The test case passes, but I am not sure I am testing this correctly.

```java
public class RowsTest
{
    private final List<RowName> rowName = Mockito.mock(List.class);
    
    private final Rows target = new Rows(rowName);

    @Test
    public void testGetMethods()
    {
        //then
        Assert.assertEquals(rowName, target.getRowName());
    }
}
```

Comment: `testGetMethods()` - if you're testing getters of `Rows` class, the test is fine, but... are you sure you want to test getters?

Comment: You shouldn't be testing Data clases in my opinion. You should be testing classes with actual logic in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing Mock tests you need to think "What functionality am I locking in so it cannot unexpectedly change in the future"

Testing data classes only ensures Java doesn't break it in the future, and Java has tests for that in their release cycle on the next versions.

Test logic you have which is custom to your program, but not the libraries and languages you use.